# Convert output of "explode" from strings to arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

How to convert the string output of "explode" into arrays?

Given this string:

```
$long_string = '("name" => "Able","company" => "Tesla","haircolor" => 
"brown","name" => "Aaaa","home" => "Kansas","shoe" => 12,)<>( "name" => 
"Bob","company" => "Target","haircolor" => "red","name" => "Bbbb","home" => 
"Ohio","shoe" => 11.5)' ;
```

Explode will produce a single array containing 2 strings.

```
$multi_strings =  explode("<>",$long_string);
```

$multi_strings is an array of 2 strings:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(112) "("name" => "Able","company" => "Tesla","haircolor" => 
  "brown","name" => "Aaaa","home" => "Kansas","shoe" => 12,)"

  [1]=> string(110) "( "name" => "Bob","company" => "Target","haircolor" => 
 "red","name" => "Bbbb","home" => "Ohio","shoe" => 11.5)"
}
```

To convert these two strings into nested arrays within the parent array it seems there should be a php function, but I can't seem to locate it.
Do I need to create my own function to accomplish this?

Comment: Where did you get this string?

Comment: This is an example:  the actual data comes from a data supplier and was supposed to be a .csv file, but it was actually a string of gargage.  It took 38 steps to turn it into this.

Comment: Parsing csv file already provides you an array.

Comment: If this took you 38 steps then I must see the actual input

Comment: Valdeir - doesn't implode convert arrays to strings?  I already have strings.

Comment: Show us the "garbage" and we'll probably be able to tell you how to decode it directly.

Comment: Andreas - the original data string is 29,363 characters long.  How would you like me to send it to you?

Comment: Use https://3v4l.org it can probably do it. Or just post a small piece, just so we can see the layout of it

Comment: Andreas:  enter this command in a browser and you'll get the string for three symbols:   https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,tsla,ge&types=quote,earnings,stats

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php `=_=`

Comment: Sammitch - I'll look at the json-decode function.  however, there's a lot of garbage embeded in the returned string:  such as   }]},"stats":{"   and   }},"GE":{"quote":{"symbol":"GE",    .   However, perhaps I can reduce the number of steps to refine using the json.  Thanks.

Comment: Thats not garbage, thats a mix of json array and json object. You can recognize it by the braces. Square for array, curly for objects. Mind the difference in definition for array in php and other languages.

Comment: It is still unclear to me if your actual data source is exactly as in $long_string, because if you did some transformation to end up with that, there must be a better way to deal with it.

Comment: fab2s - you can see the raw data with this:   "  https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,tsla,ge&types=quote,earnings,stats  "

Comment: But this source is a pure json, why not jus json_decode it (with true as second param to get an associative array directly) ? You can then manipulate it as an array to start with and loop through to build the strcu you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json_decode on the string with the second parameter true and you get a associative array as output.

```
$url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,tsla,ge&types=quote,earnings,stats";
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
Var_dump($arr);
```

See here;
I copied the string from the page and posted it as $str.
https://3v4l.org/duWrI
Two steps is all that is needed.

Comment: yup this is the way

Comment: This is just awsome.  Thank you!   Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your long string is a very poor array storage custom format. It would be a lot more efficient to use [json_encode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [serialize](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store arrays (and more) efficiently.

Now, if you're stuck with that, you *could* do this without using eval :

```
$long_string = '("name" => "Able","company" => "Tesla","haircolor" => 
"brown","name" => "Aaaa","home" => "Kansas","shoe" => 12,)<>( "name" => 
"Bob","company" => "Target","haircolor" => "red","name" => "Bbbb","home" => 
"Ohio","shoe" => 11.5)';
$parts = explode('<>', $long_string);
eval('$result = array(array' . $parts[0] . ', array' . $parts[1] . ');');
print_r($result);
```

No need to say this is ugly and pretty unsafe as the $long_string could be executed if looking like php code.

Another and safer way would be to manually parse the string and build an array out of it. But it would require more not so simple code. So again, if you can use another format, do it.

Comment: `$parts[0]...$parts[0]`? Not `$parts[0]...$parts[1]`?

Comment: fab2s - thank you.  that works.  Tell me what is so out of whach with the $long_string.  It is structured exactly like the code in example #3 in the php manual.    http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

This accomplished what I needed: 
from here:   http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
example:     Here's a function for "multi" exploding a string.

```
<?php

$long_string = '"name" => "Able","company" => "Tesla","haircolor" => "brown","name" => "Aaaa","home" => "Kansas","shoe" => 12<>"name" => "Bob","company" => "Target","haircolor" => "red","name" => "Bbbb","home" =>"Ohio","shoe" => 11.5';

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
    array_shift($delimiters);
    if($delimiters != NULL) {
        foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
             $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
        }
    }
    return  $ary;
}

// Example of use
// $string = "1-2-3|4-5|6:7-8-9-0|1,2:3-4|5";
// $delimiters = Array(",",":","|","-");

$delimiters = Array("<>",",");

$res = multiexplode($delimiters,$long_string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```